# Redundant meta attributes

Tags: html, meta-description

I generate my meta tags dynamically, they render like this:

```
<meta id="HeadContent_MetaDescription" name="description" content="Is Adobe Flash going out?  And is HTML5 taking over the world?"></meta>
```

The ID isn't needed, and it doesn't close with `/>`.  Is this OK?  Or going to cause problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not valid HTML as the `<meta`> tag has no closing element. So remove the `</meta>` tag and use the trailing /. Also, [the ID attribute is not valid for meta tags](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.4.4.2). So you would need to change your meta tag to look like this to be valid xHTML:

```
<meta name="description" content="Is Adobe Flash going out?  And is HTML5 taking over the world?" />
```

If you aren't use xHTML then you can omit the trailing slash:

```
<meta name="description" content="Is Adobe Flash going out?  And is HTML5 taking over the world?">
```

Comment: Ah ok guess this is a SO question then.  Thanks for your help.